# window.open cross scripting with same domain?

Tags: javascript

I have some javascript code that will pass data to a pop up for an intranet site. However, IE9 claims that it's cross scripting even though its the same domain. What's odd, is if I change the code from window.open to window.location, all is well. However, it's required to be a popup.

Also, the data that I am passing to the pop up contains html code.

I tried using javascript's escape and encodeURI, but have not had any luck.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
EDIT: code 
JQuery.ajax({
...
...
...
success
{
 window.open("mydomain/mypage?data="+data,"Test","width=350,height=350");
}
```

Comment: Could you show your `window.open` call and the url of the page where you hosted it?

Comment: Fast check : you're opening the first file through an http connection, not using the open function of your browser ?

Comment: can you share your code's psudo.

Comment: Why do you precise the domain in your url ? Is that relative or not ?

Comment: If its the same domain, can you try a relative URL or absolute URL without the domain?

Comment: I tried relative and absolute. neither work.

Comment: Can you produce a working example of your problem accessible on the internet ?

Comment: instead of looking at the window.open, are you certain the ajax call itself is not cross-site?

Comment: yea, everything is on our test server. I cannot produce a working example on the internet. It's sensitive data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see on jsfiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/DKehT/1/

you even dont need to encode. encoding is done automatically

```
var a="<htm>"
window.open("http://mydomain.com/mypage?data="+a,"Test1","width=350,height=350");
```